# Git- Local branch checkout in Visual Studio 2019 does not restore the branch workspace

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, git-checkout

I have 2 feature branches namely feature_1 and feature_2. The files in both branches are different. I commit a few changes to the feature_1 branch and then checkout feature_2 branch using Visual Studio 2019.

On checkout I expect to see only feature_2 related files, instead, feature_1 files are seen.

Closing and re-opening the Visual Studio restores the workspace to the feature_2 branch correctly. But close/re-open on branch switch takes too much time.

How to restore the working files for the checked-out feature branch without going through close/re-open hassle?